# marquee scroll in notification via RemoteViews

Tags: android, textview, android-notifications, android-scroll, android-remoteview

I am trying to marquee scroll text in notification bar using `RemoteViews`. Also, I was able to debug the code to see that the `TextView$Marquee` was infact running the system of marquee scroll but the `TextView` on the UI wasn't actually scrolling the text..

Anybody has any solution to this problem?

I couldn't comment so I opened a new topic. Also, there was no reply to that .
[Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704319/android-notification-textview-marquee-do-not-work/19360551#19360551?newreg=c4f74bb1ce1640b3a2c158b9c55b8b47)